# Parse is working for push notifications? 8/15

Tags: parse-platform

Was working fine, but today did not sent push notifications to my apps I tried by api and by parse web but nothing parse status is working fine but not for me. Any one else with that problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sometimes have the same issue. Just wait for a few more time and the pushes come through. I think it maybe is Parse's delay, or it is just the nature of remote push not being real time.

Comment: still not coming through?

Comment: No, I get one push 2 hours ago but from there still nothing.